# Memory sharing for multiple PI logins

Tags: raspbian

When I login to PI (SSH via Putty)from multiple machines using same account (PI/Raspberry) will memory be shared among the different login's ? I assume some memory overhead will be required to maintain the connection to multiple machines but the memory required for the login session will be shared (which includes any running programs for that session) ?

Update : I require minimizing memory usage of PI, so want to ensure memory is not wasted managing multiple user sessions

Comment: Linux handles memory on the Raspberry Pi in exactly the same way as any other Linux box.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. If you would explain why you want to know, maybe it would be easier to answer.

Comment: @Bex please see update

Comment: I understand you are concerned about the memory. Generally, if you do less, the memory cost will be smaller. If you don't need multiple logins, then minimizing them would lessen the memory impact. On the other hand, if you do need them, then the cost is irrelevant, as long as there is memory enough left to do what you need to do, right? If you want to know exactly how much memory every login session use, then have a look at `top` or `ps -eo cmd,sid,sz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, multiple instances of the same user logging into the same machine will not share the same memory.  They might be able to access the same threads, being the same owner, however typically each instance is completely isolated from each other.

I've checked this with my RasPi 2, using two different TTYs.  They spawn their own instances of Bash - the shell that the Pi uses to interpret commands.  However, if you're *really* concerned about trying to save ~5 KB of memory per login, then I'd like to know what's sucking up all of your memory.

Additionally, I'd suggest you look into using Minibian - it takes the original Raspbian image available off of Raspberry Pi Foundation's website and strips it down to the bare bones.  This has an added benefit of keeping everything running within around 25 MB of RAM and about a GB of storage.

Comment: how much memory memory more than 25MB does Raspbian require ?

Comment: @blue-sky Using my own Raspi2 imaged with a relatively clean instance of the newest Raspbian, I can see that my memory usage is hovering at about 32MB.  So, really, not much more to really be concerned about it.

Comment: +1 To clear up an ambiguity, those are separate shell instances **but** they *do* share (readonly) memory, since they are the same thing.  Also, logging in by `ssh` will create an `sshd` instance for each login.  Those are in the 5 KB range and also share memory; looking at two in `top` on a pi, the RES is ~6200 and the SHR is ~5400.  That last number (shared mem) indicates a sizeable chunk of each of them is shared and most likely, the same thing.  So each one has actually only added < 1 KB.  `bash` is probably similar.  Hence the first login will add about 10 KB, each one after that ~2 KB.

Comment: P.S. *"Minibian [keeps] everything running within around 25 MB of RAM"*  -> That's about the same as regular Raspbian if you are not running a GUI.  There is in fact not much to strip out of the base system in that sense.   I just checked a headless raspbian wheezy pi -- **21.6 MB** in use.

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah, I just now realized that bit.  I typically utilize my Pi headless - I don't even think of desktop memory usage.  The only time I really considered the memory usage of the Pi was when I was trying to run a Minecraft server off it - didn't last very long, I love my mods too much.

That said, I also run a few things that might be sucking up memory - `Apache2` and `vsfptd` come to mind.  And while not recommended, there's another kilo or two to save by killing rsyslogd.